# Вставить строку после определенного тега

Tags: php

Я копирую удаленный html файл с помощью CURL и получаю переменную $content в которой содержится вся верстка страницы.
Мне нужно в эту переменную контента вставить собственный тег после тега `<head>`. Я делаю это так:

```
$substr = '<head>';
$attachment = '<base href="https://example.com" target="_blank">';

$newstring = str_replace($substr, $substr.$attachment, $content);
```

Проблема в том, что некоторые страницы имеют не фиксированный теги `<head>`, например - `<head xmlnsog="http://ogp.me/ns#">` и в этом случае мой код не работает.

Как мне вычислить этот неопределенный тег `<head>` и вставить свою строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '123<head xmlnsog="http://ogp.me/ns#">456';
$attachment = '<base href="https://example.com" target="_blank">';

echo preg_replace('#(<head.*>)#isU', '$1'.$attachment, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$substr = '<head>';
$attachment = '<base href="https://example.com" target="_blank">';

$newstring = preg_replace('/(<head[^>]*>)/im', '$1'.$attachment, $substr);
```